# R programming - error : non-numeric argument to binary operator?

Tags: r

I am running this code (below) to add error bars onto my bar chart, i am trying to to work out the standard deviation (sd) of shannons diversity index
The code works up until the second/third last line

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=shannon-sd, ymax=shannon+sd), width=0.2,
position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

This error code keeps coming up

```
"Error in shannon - sd : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
```

but this is my data...

```
Exposure  | genus      | shannon  | sd
----------------------------------------------
Exposed   | Crustacean | 0.000000 | 0.00000000
Exposed   | Mollusc    | 1.199625 | 0.13291129
Exposed   | Seaweed    | 1.513125 | 0.42093822
Sheltered | Crustacean | 0.025500 | 0.07212489
Sheltered | Mollusc    | 1.156750 | 0.26763341
Sheltered | Seaweed    | 1.848125 | 0.27264128
```

anyone know where im going wrong?

```
library(ggplot2)
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Function to calculate the mean and the standard deviation
# for each group
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++
# data : a data frame
# varname : the name of a column containing the variable
#to be summariezed
# groupnames : vector of column names to be used as
# grouping variables
data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
require(plyr)
summary_func <- function(x, col){
c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
}
data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
varname)
data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
return(data_sum)
}
df3 <- data_summary(diversity, varname="shannon",
groupnames=c("Exposure", "genus"))
# Convert dose to a factor variable
df3$genus=as.factor(df3$genus)
head(df3)
p <- ggplot(diversity, aes(x=genus, y=shannon, fill = location)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5, position=position_dodge()) + theme_minimal() +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=shannon-sd, ymax=shannon+sd), width=0.2,
position=position_dodge(0.9))
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: `sd` is also the name of a base function, the best option is to change that name asap, before you have more code using it. Another option is to restart R, maybe there's a names conflict somewhere. And, are you plotting `diversity` or `df3`? The code is unclear, `sd` seems to exist in `df3`, after calling the custom summary stats function

Answer (score 0):

You've shared a bunch of code but it's not totally clear what you're trying to accomplish with it all because most of it doesn't seem to make into the actual plot.

One thing I see that's generally not a good idea is that you define one function (`data_summary()`) inside another (`summary_fun()`).

Also your plotting code calls `fill = location` but it's not clear where `location` is coming from in your data.

So here's my best guess of what you were going for but please clarify if that's not it:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(Exposure = c("Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Sheltered", "Sheltered", "Sheltered"), genus = c("Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed", "Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed"), shannon = c(0, 1.199625, 1.513125, 0.0255, 1.15675, 1.848125), sd = c(0, 0.13291129, 0.42093822, 0.07212489, 0.26763341, 0.27264128)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = genus, y = shannon, fill = Exposure)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.5,
           position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = shannon - sd, ymax = shannon + sd),
                width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thankyou so much! That is exactly what i was going for! I am 3rd year and my supervisors expect me to learn how to code in 1 month on my own, and its proving quite difficult.